# Cannot implement Websockets instead of Long-polling in IIS 7.5 and Console

Tags: .net, signalr, windows-server-2008-r2

I have implemented cross-domain SignalR example using IIS 7.5 and a console listener (on port 8080) but cannot get the transport to use anything better than long-polling.

In order to add webbsocket support I have followed the instructions in [Hosting a SignalR application on Windows 2008r2 and IIS 7.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timlee/archive/2013/03/21/hosting-a-signalr-application-on-windows-2008r2-and-iis-7-5.aspx#config)

However, since I am implementing this as a cross domain call to a console application I wonder if there is something I have missed.

Done so far in the IIS

- Updated the Signalr Application's Web.config file.. [modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"]
- Add a reference to the json2.js library
- Added META-tag in calling page.. [meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"]
- Using .Net 4.0 (4.5) and integrated application pool
- Updated to latest SignalR as of today (1.0.1)

The console is using latest SignalR references as of today

Console listening on port 8080:
Target Framework: .Net 4.5

Any ideas of what I am missing?

/Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing IIS8. Read the documentation on supported platforms: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms

Comment: Hi David. I sure would like to upgrade but for that I need to switch to Windows Server 2012, right?

I guess I'll have to bite the bullet on that and take your advice

Comment: Yes, or don't use websockets.